# how do i set the speed when using the dronekit lib to create way points "mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_NAV_WAYPOINT"

Tags: python-3.x, dronekit-python, dronekit

what i am doing is basically building a mobile app that sends waypoints to the companion computer of the autopilot(pihawk), it works fine but the problem i have is that, its default speed is too much while running the mission, which affects the UAV in precisely getting to the waypoints, is there a way to make the UAV run the mission slowly? Probably in one of this parameter:

```
cmds.add(Command( 0, 0, 0, mavutil.mavlink.MAV_FRAME_GLOBAL_RELATIVE_ALT, mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_NAV_WAYPOINT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, point4.lat, point4.lon, 14))
```